# Making a static function visible only through child class

Tags: php

Let's say that I have some functions in my abstract parent class. I want these to only be accessible by the children classes, so I mark the functions `protected` (non-static).

```
abstract class ParentClass
{      
  protected function myFunction()
  {
     //implementation
  }
}
```

My problem is the following: I have a few children classes and most of them use the aforementioned `protected` functions. I want to create a child class though, which allows the programmer to use those functions directly.

So basically:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
  public static function myAwesomeFunction()
  {
    parent::myFunction();
  }      
}
```

This is what I want to do. I want the user to be able to call the function (can be with the same name - `myFunction` in the child class) in a static way **from the child class, but not from the parent class** (that's why I don't want to make the function public, plus since I want it to be static, marking the class abstract doesn't help with this).

To be able to call

```
ChildClass::myAwesomeFunction();
```

but not to be able to do

```
ParentClass:myFunction();
```

Is there a trick to achieve this? If not, what is the best practice to do this? Is the only way really to enumerate all the functions I want and have them call the parent's method (like I have in my example)?

Comment: Explain why do you need this? If method is protected, you cannot call it unless call it inside a child class.

Comment: I don't want `ParentClass::myFunction()` to be callable. I want to force the user to use the functions in the children classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the abstract to be `protected static` and then use the `self` keyword in the child:

```
abstract class A
{
    protected static function _foo() {
        echo "foo\n";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static function foo() {
        self::_foo();
    }
}

A::_foo(); // fatal
B::foo(); // works
```

Given that, I'm not really crazy about this technique, and I would generally recommend avoiding static methods -- then it simply becomes a matter of defining the abstract protected and letting the child inherit it.